# How to highlight active link with Snap?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

Could someone give an example of highlighting the "active" link on the menu on the site with [Snap](http://snapframework.com/)? Or at least tell me how you would go about it - as I have no idea.

In other web-frameworks I usually set a context variable called `active` to what the active page should be, and then my html simply checks it:

```
<ul> 
   {% ifequal active "home" %}
   <li class="active">
   {% else %}
   <li>
   {% endifqual %}
   <a href="/">Home</a>
   </li>

   {% ifequal active "about" %}
   <li class="active">
   {% else %}
   <li>
   {% endifequal %}
   <a href="/about">About Us</a>
   </li>

 </ul>
```

There are splices in heist, but I am not sure how you would use them to figure out what the current url is or set the context variable.

### My Solution

Thanks to @mightybyte and @Adam Bergmark, I've settled on the following:

Haskell code:

```
menuenuEntrySplice :: MonadSnap m => HeistT m Template
menuEntrySplice = do
               requestPath <- lift $ withRequest (return . rqURI)
               node <- getParamNode
               let setActive n = if getAttribute "href" node == Just (decodeUtf8 requestPath)
                                    then setAttribute "class" "active" n
                                    else n


               let aNode = Element "a" [("href", fromMaybe "/" $ getAttribute "href" node)] $ [TextNode (nodeText node)]
               let liNode = setActive $ Element "li" [] [aNode]

               return [liNode]


app :: SnapletInit App App
app = makeSnaplet "app" "An snaplet example application." Nothing $ do
    ....
    addSplices [ ("menuEntry", liftHeist menuEntrySplice) ]
    return $ App h s a
```

And here is now it's used in HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
      <menuEntry href="/">Home</menuEntry>
          <menuEntry href="/contact">Contact</menuEntry>
</ul>
```

which produces:

```
<ul class="nav">
     <li class="active"> <a href="/">Home</a> </li>
     <li> <a href="/contact">Contact</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What about giving `body` and your `li`s an `id` and then doing `#page-home #nav-home, #page-about #nav-about`?

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather keep logic in code, not css/html :-) (Yes, I do realize that my solution is with logic in html - but I didn't say it was the best :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the snapframework.com site, we do it with javascript.  At the end of [site.js](http://snapframework.com/media/js/site.js) you'll find this code that adds the appropriate class to the appropriate link.

```
if ($.url.segment(0)) {
  $('.nav li.'+$.url.segment(0)).addClass('active');
} else {
  $('.nav .home').addClass('active');
}
```

If you want to do this with Heist, then you'll need to use a paradigm a bit different from what your template above uses.  The whole point of Heist (aided by Haskell's strong static type system) is to provide the strongest possible separation between view and business logic, so you can't use Haskell constructs like loops or conditionals directly in your templates.  The answer is to create new tag (implemented with a splice) that does exactly what you want.  In your template you will use it like this:

```
<ul>
  <menuLink href="/">Home</menuLink>
  <menuLink href="/about">About Us</menuLink>
</ul>
```

First of all, notice how much cleaner this is.  In your approach, you had to repeat the same code for every link.  Here we're able to keep the template DRY and it reads quite nicely.

To implement the menuLink tag you'll need a splice splice that looks something like this:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift) -- transformers 
import Data.Text.Encoding (decodeUtf8)
import Text.XmlHtml (getAttribute, setAttribute, elementTag)

menuLinkSplice :: MonadSnap m => HeistT m Template
menuLinkSplice = do
    requestPath <- lift $ withRequest (return . rqURI)
    node <- getParamNode
    let addActive n = if getAttribute "href" n == Just (decodeUtf8 requestPath)
                           then setAttribute "class" "active" n
                           else n
    return [addActive (node { elementTag = "a" })]
```

Then, to put it all together, you need to bind that splice to the menuLink tag.  In a Snap application you'll do that with:

```
addSplices [ ("menuLink", liftHeist menuLinkSplice) ]
```

You also might find my blog post [Looping and Control Flow in Heist](http://softwaresimply.blogspot.com/2011/04/looping-and-control-flow-in-heist.html) helpful (as well as some of my other posts with the "heist" tag).

Comment: Great answer! Just what I was looking for. Sorry for stupid question, but in `let addActive node =...`, what is the  `addActive`?

Comment: And how can I make the splice output `<li><a href="...">Blah</a></li>` instead of just the `a` tag? I'm not really going the right way with this: `return [addActive (node (node {elementTag ="li" {elementTag="a"} ...` ???

Comment: addActive is just a function he defines locally there, a matter of formatting.

Comment: @AdamBergmark Aaaa! Thanks! The node variable names being the same really confused me.

Comment: And in case you missed my IRC comment, check the definition of Node in http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmlhtml/0.2.0.2/doc/html/Text-XmlHtml.html to nest elements.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was a bad choice of names on my part.  I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Heist requires you to put even this sort of logic into Haskell rather than Heist. See, for example, this example from the [docs for Text.Templating.Heist](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/heist/0.8.1.1/doc/html/Text-Templating-Heist.html):

```
link :: Text -> Text -> X.Node
link target text = X.Element "a" [("href", target)] [X.TextNode text]

loginLink :: X.Node
loginLink = link "/login" "Login"

logoutLink :: Text -> X.Node
logoutLink user = link "/logout" (T.append "Logout " user)

loginLogoutSplice :: Splice MyAppMonad
loginLogoutSplice = do
    user <- lift getUser
    return [maybe loginLink logoutLink user]
```

Here instead of passing a Bool to the template, and letting the template perform the if/then logic, all logic is performed at the Haskell level. That's the best answer I can give. I'm unfamiliar with Heist; I know that you can give a splice arguments but it is unclear to me how to accomplish your particular task.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how to use this at all. What's more, the initial project that Snap generates for you, has functions that look nothing like the Snap documentation or their examples, and I don't know what to put where. Frustrating... :-(

Comment: Yeah the heist documentation seems to be lacking quite a lot. Try #snapframework on freenode irc.